# I get "No message available" in postman response from api spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I'm programming an Api REST in Spring boot and I have an error from Postman while I'm trying to fetch the users, i literally went out of ideas:

```
{
"timestamp": "2023-03-06T03:46:26.764+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/api/usuarios/allUsers"
}
```

and this is my project's code base:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UsuariosRepository repo;
@GetMapping("/allUser")
@ResponseBody
public List<Usuarios> fetchUsers() {
    return repo.findAll();
 }
}
```

this is my main class where I've already checked:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FitnessApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FitnessApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

this is the repository where I've already checked too:

```
@Repository
 public interface UsuariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuarios,Long> {   
 }
```

and this is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuarios {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String nombre;

private String apellido_paterno;

private String apellido_materno;

private String correo;

private String telefono;

private String password;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido_paterno() {
    return apellido_paterno;
}

public void setApellido_paterno(String apellido_paterno) {
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
}

public String getApellido_materno() {
    return apellido_materno;
}

public void setApellido_materno(String apellido_materno) {
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

I went out of ideas, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the url you typed `"/api/usuarios/allUsers"` it should be `"https://localhost:\<application-port>/api/users/allUser"`.

As @Bejond mentioned 404 means no resource found . Usually errors in the 400s indicates a client-side issue.

Answer (score 3):

404 means the url you enter in postman doesn't exist on server. Based on your code, the url should be "http://localhost:8080/api/users/allUser".